# Python2 Popen in Windows

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I was trying to execute a windows console exe program using Popen on python 2.

```py
import subprocess

#
# Other codes
#

p = subprocess.Popen(path_of_exe, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

output = p.stdout.read()
print output
p.stdin.write('mystring')
```

The program prints `Command>` when the program executed.
However, the output variable has nothing about the string.
It is always an empty string.

If I change `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` to `stdout=sys.stdout`, it printed outputs.

However, I need to get the output to parse the result from my input.
So, I want to grep the output was program.
I'm not sure why the subprocess.PIPE doesn't work.

Also, when I changed to `stdout=sys.stdout`, its output printed `Command>` infinitely.
The program should print the `Command>` only one time before I put string.

I also tried to get the output using `p.communicate()[0]`, but it doesn't work.

I'm no idea with this behavior. When I worked in a Linux environment, there is no problem like that. I might think it is a problem of stdin or stdout buffer even though flush not worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have tackled this problem before. Try and use this syntax when using Popn on Python2.

p=subprocess.Popen([python(where your python is located), file name, args],stdout=PIPE).stdout.read()

Let me know if this worked out for ya!

Comment: I don't want to execute python scripts using Popen. Suggested way is to execute python script. I would like to execute exe (PE file). So, I think this is not the issue for this problem.